# *non-uniform* $ACC^0$ and above classes

Tags: complexity-theory, circuits

$NEXP$ smallest class above $ACC^0$ that we know is separated from $ACC^0$.

We do not know if either $NP$ or $P/poly$ is in $ACC^0$.

Suppose every problem in $NP$ can be solved in polynomial time with polynomial sized advice string (that is $NP\subseteq P/poly$ holds) however the circuit that computes it needs only $ACC^0$ type structure?

Would that mean $NP$ is in *non-uniform* $ACC^0$ or *uniform* $ACC^0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would imply that NP is in non-uniform ACC<sup>0</sup>. While in some circumstances non-uniformity can be removed, this one doesn't seem to be one of them, though you never know...

Comment: my query is simple I will ask here is non-uniform ACC^0 contained in any uniform ACC^i or at least uniform TC^i at any i>0?

Comment: That's definitely false. Non-uniform ACC^0 contains uncomputable functions.

Comment: how about non-uniform $ACC^0\cap EXPSPACE$? Is it in any uniform $ACC^i \cap EXPSPACE$ or at least uniform $TC^i\cap EXPSPACE$ at any i>0?

Comment: I don't know, I'm not a complexity oracle.

Comment: sorry about that.. thank you for your good help though

Comment: sorry again you mentioned 'some circumstances non-uniformity can be removed' is this in standard complexity theory texts like Arora Barak?

Comment: It should be. I don't remember said circumstances. I could also be wrong.